# Delete a Has-Many Relationship ONLY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-many

I have a: `has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, :join_table => "friends_peoples".`

To add a friend I do: `@people.followers << @friend` which create the relationship and a new person profile.

Now I'd like to delete the relationship ONLY and not the person profile.

I tried `@people.friends.delete(guilty.id)` but it deletes the person profile and not the relationship.

Any idea?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
@people.friends.delete(guilty)
```

Comment: Works! Was easy! Thanks a lot

Comment: FYI delete skips callbacks. Use `@people.friends.destroy(guilty)` to get the callbacks to work.